# How do I calculate the standard deviation between weighted measurements?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, weighted-average

I have several weighted values for which I am taking a weighted average.  I want to calculate a weighted standard deviation using the weighted values and weighted average.  How would I modify the typical standard deviation to include weights on each measurement?

This is the standard deviation formula I am using.

[image]

When I simply use each weighted value for '*x*' and the weighted average for '\bar{*x*}', the result seems smaller than it should be.

Comment: How is this question related to this site? Isn't this belongs to [Mathematics SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @DavidArenburg This is something I am trying to program and likely others have/will also use in the future. I just added more to the answer I posted to identify how to efficiently code this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found [this wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_square_weighted_deviation) page discussing data of equal significance vs weighted data.  The correct way to calculate the biased weighted estimator of variance is

[image],

though the following, on-the-fly implementation, is more efficient computationally as it does not require calculating the weighted average before looping over the sum on the weighted differences squared

[image].

Despite my skepticism, I tried both and got the exact same results.

Note, be sure to use the weighted average

[image].

Comment: Note that the mean is also calculated using the weights (i.e. be careful to use the weighted mean in that formula, not the usual unweighted mean).

Comment: @RobertDodier good point. I did not make that explicit but I will for completeness sake.

Comment: That last sentence should say "weighted mean", not "weighted error", right? I suppose the weighted error would be the difference between x_i and this value.